# How to add a title in a GetLegendGraphic Request

Tags: geoserver, sld

The GetLegendGraphic request works well. I display the legend at a fixed position in my viewer using OpenLayers. But I would like to know if there is any way to add some custom text to the legend.

The legend that geoserver produces is like this: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/_images/samplelegend.png

But I need to produce a legend with a title: http://minus.com/m4AP102Jj

Does anyone know if the GetLegendGraphic request in GeoServer, or the SLD style have a way to add this?

**UPDATE (23/08/12)**

For now I´ll use a litle trick to add a title by adding in my SLD another custom rule above all others that not match any other rules:

Example:

```
<sld:Rule>
  <sld:Name>[NAME]</sld:Name>
    <sld:Title>[TITLE]</sld:Title>
    <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>[PROPERTY_NAME]</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>[SOME_VALUE_THAT_NOT_MATCH_OTHER_RULES]</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    </ogc:Filter>
    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
      <sld:Fill>
        <sld:CssParameter name="fill">[MATCH_BACKGROUND_COLOR]</sld:CssParameter>
      </sld:Fill>
    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>      
</sld:Rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Legend-Title-tc4987789.html#none

Comment: The link provided is not working.