# How to add legend heading to a GeoServer WMS layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, legend

I am trying to publish some layers in QGIS (version 2.14.0 Essen) to create WMS in geoserver. In ArcMap I can define legend heading

[image: legend heading]

. I have not encounter any option in QGIS.  Since I am learning QGIS and Geoserver, wanted to make sure if I am missing any option (or any plugin can help)?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've handled it is by using the Layer's title manually in HTML along with GeoServer's generated legend graphic.

Here's an example auto-generated legend out of GeoServer:

[image]

I believe that if you have two rules, then the title gets printed. See [this question/answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28286/how-to-add-a-title-in-a-getlegendgraphic-request).

So the short answer is, yes, there is a title available for use in GeoServer. And when you use it, you can get it to appear in your autogenerated legend, but it's a little clumsy. (And it should be obvious that you can do nearly anything with QGIS' legends =P).